# InputMask запрет чисел

Tags: javascript

Использую плагин InputMask, нужно запертить в первых  3 символах запретить 3 8 0, как это сделать, сейчас маска такая.

```
var im = new Inputmask("+38 (099) -999-99-99");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var im = new Inputmask("+38 (0[99]) [-999-99-99]");
```

Comment: Какой простой синтаксис, я влюбился в InputMask

Comment: @Leonid Сработало?

Comment: @Leonid: тут столько вопросов по допилу этого плагина, что любовь эта быстро проходит))

Comment: Я не знаю, это у автора вопроса спросить надо, я лично сомневаюсь, что-то тут не сходится... Про любовь я пошутил, я люблю все контролировать сам.